# Deleting dynamically added divs with their children elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I simulate a table with the following code:

```
<div id="edit_table">
    <div class="table_row">
        <div class="table_cell">
            <input type="text" id="Dt_of_Birth">
        </div>
        <div class="table_cell">
            <input type="text" id="F_Name">
        </div>
        <div class="table_cell">
            <input type="text" id="L_Name">
        </div>
        <div class="table_cell">
            <button id="del_row">Delete Row</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<button id="add_row">Add Row</button>
```

and add rows in this table dynamically with

```
$('#add_row').on('click', function() {
    $('.table_row:last').append('<div class="table_row"><div class="table_cell"><input type="text" id="Dt_of_Birth"></div><div class="table_cell"><input type="text" id="F_Name"></div><div class="table_cell"><input type="text" id="L_Name"></div><div class="table_cell"><button id="del_row">Delete Row</button> </div></div>');
});
```

When I try to delete a row, clicking the delete button in the row, it behaves erratically. If there are rows below that in which I click the 'Delete' button, all these rows downwards are deleted. How do I stop this and delete only that row in which I click the button.

my code for deleting specific row is :

```
$(document).on('click', '#del_row', function() {
    alert('Delete button clicked ....');
    $(this).parent().parent('div .table_row').remove();
});
```

- which of course does not work correctly.

Please help me with the correct jQuery logic for deletion of specific row

Thanks in advance for any help ....

Comment: Your delete button ID is not unique.  If you have more than one of these buttons then jQuery is only going to select one of them.  Likely the first on the page, but the Javascript DOM API makes no guarantees.

Comment: In this part: `$(document).on('click', '#del_row', function(){` Change document by '.table_row'.

Comment: Draco 18s has pointed it out correctly. This point along with the construct suggested by Azim helped me out.

Answer (score 0):

Your should append `.table_row` in `#add_row` not in `.table_row:last` and your `#del_row` click event should be like below.

```js
$('#add_row').on('click', function () {
     $('#edit_table').append('<div class="table_row"><div class="table_cell"><input type="text" id="Dt_of_Birth"></div><div class="table_cell"><input type="text" id="F_Name"></div><div class="table_cell"><input type="text" id="L_Name"></div><div class="table_cell"><button id="del_row">Delete Row</button> </div></div>');
});

$(document).on('click', '#del_row', function () {            
    $(this).closest('.table_row').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="edit_table">
    <div class="table_row">
        <div class="table_cell"><input type="text" id="Dt_of_Birth"></div>
        <div class="table_cell"><input type="text" id="F_Name"></div>
        <div class="table_cell"><input type="text" id="L_Name"></div>
        <div class="table_cell"><button id="del_row">Delete Row</button> </div>
    </div>
</div>
<button id="add_row">Add Row</button>
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: You should use a class instead of a id for the buttons.

Comment: Using `class` is better, but not a problem in this case. @Andy

Comment: Thank you so much Azim - your answer solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

When you add a row, it creates a row below the delete button? Maybe if you put the delete button outside the div.table_row it would work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I changed the following:

- changed #del_row to .del_row since ids must be unique
- changed the add handler to append to the container instead of the last row
- changed the parent selector in the delete handler

```js
$(function(){
    $('#add_row').on('click', function(){
        $('#edit_table').append('<div class="table_row"><div class="table_cell"><input type="text" id="Dt_of_Birth"></div><div class="table_cell"><input type="text" id="F_Name"></div><div class="table_cell"><input type="text" id="L_Name"></div><div class="table_cell"><button class="del_row">Delete Row</button> </div></div>');
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.del_row', function() {
        alert('Delete button clicked ....');
        $(this).parents('div .table_row').remove();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="edit_table">

</div>

<button id="add_row">Add Row</button>
```